# Issues with Dates

Tags: php, date, fatal-error

I have a need to get the range for Mon-Sun for each week, beginning from current.

This is what I came up with:

```
$range = 0;
$weekNumber =  date("W", strtotime(date('l j  F Y') . '  ' . ($range) . ' days'));
$weekYear =  date("Y", strtotime(date('l j  F Y') . '  ' . ($range) . ' days'));

$week_array = getWeekDates($weekNumber, $weekYear);

function getWeekDates($week, $year) {
    $dto = new DateTime();
    $ret['mon'] = $dto->setISODate($year, $week)->format('Y-m-d');
    $ret['tue'] = $dto->modify('+1 days')->format('Y-m-d');
    $ret['wed'] = $dto->modify('+1 days')->format('Y-m-d');
    $ret['thu'] = $dto->modify('+1 days')->format('Y-m-d');
    $ret['fri'] = $dto->modify('+1 days')->format('Y-m-d');
    $ret['sat'] = $dto->modify('+1 days')->format('Y-m-d');
    $ret['sun'] = $dto->modify('+1 days')->format('Y-m-d');
    return $ret;
}
```

It works on my local WampServer (5.3.4), but when I try t run it on Godaddy (5.2.17), getting this error:

*Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /home/.....php on line ($ret['mon'] = $dto->setISODate($year, $week)->format('Y-m-d');)*

Comment: what is the php version on godaddy and your local wamp server? Probably incompatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [The Documentation,](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php) The return value for "setISODate" and "modify" changed from NULL to DateTime starting in 5.3. This is why it works in the newer php environment but not the older one.

To make your code compatible, change the code to something like this:

```
$dto->setISODate($year, $week);
$ret['mon'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
$dto->modify('+1 days');
$ret['tue'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
//so forth for rest of days
```

Here is another way to write the function:

```
function getWeekDates($week, $year) {
    $dto = new DateTime();
    $dto->setISODate($year, $week);
    $keys = array('mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun');
    $ret = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
        $ret[$keys[$i]] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
        $dto->modify('+1 days');
    }
    return $ret;
}
```